# How does sleep affect anesthesia?

Tags: sleep, surgery, neuroscience, anesthesia

Before surgery that requires anesthesia the patient is told stuff like don't eat.
Some people cannot sleep well prior to surgery.

Can having a full night or regular good sleep fair better for keeping a patient under or not slipping into a coma?

On the other hand, if a patient is known to come out of anesthesia be kept awake the night prior to stay under better?

What other ways could too much or not enough sleep could affect surgery?

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. This helps to provide an answer which will be more helpful.

Comment: @ChrisRogers how it this? I am just curious on what people would say here. I don't know and SE is where I ask.

Comment: There are valid reasons for pre-surgical instructions such as not eating, but what you're asking is very broad and vague. As @ChrisRogers pointed out, I think you should do some research on your own and narrow this question down.